# Setting table with default value performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 with a `name` column. What is the best performance to give the column the default value when I insert a row or in the insert query, I insert the default value?

Comment: I suspect the difference will be negligible. When in doubt, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I'd be less concerned about the performance and more concerned about where, functionally, I want the default to live -- on the client side or the database side (with the latter being a lot more likely, if you don't want every client to decide for themselves). If you've come to the point where the only thing left to optimize is inserting default values (and you've covered everything else possible, like bulk inserting) I'd say you're having a very interesting use case, but it's still a lot more likely that you're focusing on the wrong thing altogether.